# SharePoint 2013 document generation -Can't open document

Tags: document-template

I'm trying to use a document library to generate documents.

I have created 6 content types (as I need multiple templates) and associated document templates to them. I read somewhere I should be using `.docx` instead of `.dotx` as a template.

But I can't get it to work. I get this error:

[image]

> We're sorry. We can't open DocumentName.docx because we found a problem with its contents."

Comment: Can you check wether the template document .docx can be opened correctly? What SharePoint version are you using?

Comment: Go it rolling with multiple doc lib. But going to try multiple content types when ave got some time

Comment: I have just posted the step-by-step solution to this on my post here: [Solution: "We're sorry. We can't open {file} because we found a problem with its contents."](https://sharepointlibrarian.com/2018/07/23/solution-were-sorry-we-cant-open-file-because-we-found-a-problem-with-its-contents/) Basically you just need to save the `.dotx` template instead as a `.docx` file and use that as the template.